# How to pass file in GITHUB to a python script and automating with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, github, automation, jenkins-pipeline

I have a python script which automates websphere roles mapping , as of now that file has been set as an environment variable.
But now I need to have that file in GITHUB and pass it via a jenkins job how can i achieve this?
will try to elaborate more below is my code sample

```
print("*******************")
import sys
import java.lang.System as system
import os
doUpdateAccessIDs = 0
aclfilename=os.environ['APPLICATIONSECURITYINPUTFILE']
if aclfilename == "":
    raise Exception("YOU MUST PROVIDE THE FULL FILEPATH TO THE ACL FILE through the environment variable APPLICATIONSECURITYINPUTFILE")
    sys.exit
```

the **APPLICATIONSECURITYINPUTFILE** is a txt file set as environment var in shell.
now it has to be read from GITHUB repo rather then from local.
how can i set this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what is you location of the python file in your git repository and send it to the python with the pass for example -- $WORKSPACE/data/myfile.txt (the pass to the file)

--file_path $WORKSPACE/data/myfile.txt

I adjust my code to assist:

```
import argparse

def print_options(options):
    print "file_path: %s" % options.file_path


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--file_path", help="APPLICATION SECURITY INPUT FILE", default="/opt/myfile")


    options=parser.parse_args()
    print_options(options)
    return vars(options)


def main():
    print ' *** start jenkins job script ***'
    option = get_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```